Ptr-Net with Constraints
I'm currently working on a research problem that's similar to subset-sum with a bit more rules. Imagine you have a table, each entry has various features (A,B,C) and you have specific constraints. For example, you can say: Find me 6 entries where A adds up to 20, B averages to 5, and the minimum of C is 1 (the rules won't change but the number of entries might).
I recently found a Ptr-Net that picks out the highest probability of each entry, the paper is here if you want to read it. In the original research paper, they tried it on TSP and other combinatorics problems, but they didn't have a problem where you can state your constraints.
I currently am thinking of adding a constraint vector as part of the input, but I'm not sure if that's the smartest way. I'd love to hear your advice and suggestions, thank you!

Can you please reformulate the title as specific question? The current title is not really a question and there isn't really any question in the post's body.
